# React/Redux : Detect and exectute instructions before component destruction

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Ola,

In my redux state, I have a `isEditing` boolean value, initiate at `false`, to manage a profile editing mode. I create a redux action to toggle this state. Below, some screen of the component render.

[image: Edit mode off]

[image: Edit mode on]

It works in most cases:

When I click on Edit name, I toggle to `true` and display the edit form

When I click on Save (or Cancel), it perform (or not) api request, then toggle to `false`, displaying the initial component

But if I start editing then quit page manualy (via logo link or url), and then come back to this page, obviously, the edit mode is still active at `true`.

I would like to put my state to `false` when I leave page, but I don't find any option to dispatch an action before component destroyed (like old componentWillUnmount() class programming method or beforeUnmount VueJS equivalent)

PS : I use react router V6. It seems a hook was implemented during beta but never released, and no news since :(

An alternative is to force value to `false` on component creation, with `useEffect`. It works, but I think it's not the right place. I see the edit mode opened then close in my ui during a few ms.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the clean up on an [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
   useEffect(() => {
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      // make redux call to toggle edit mode
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. Both yours and Mauro Tenti solutions worked. Can you please make a rock paper scissors lizard spock game to to decide between you what solution is the best? :D

Comment: But I'll accept your solution, because it's the first time I heard about cleanup() and I think it could be interesting to make some research

Comment: Oh, cleanup is not a react reserved word. So both answers are equal, perfect :)

Comment: The return type of the useEffect is a function, but naming it makes it more readable. The example I posted comes directly from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could dispatch an action in the useEffect return value like `useEffect(() => { return () => dispatch(changeEditMode(false)) }, [])`. It is mostly similar to a componentWillUnmount().

Comment: Thank you. Both yours and Mircea Matei solutions worked. Can you please make a rock paper scissors lizard spock game to to decide between you what solution is the best? :D